# How to avoid ambiguous references with overridden methods with default parameters involving nullable types?

Tags: c#, nullable, default-parameters

I have some methods like the following:

```
static public int GetInt(int _default = 0)
{
    // do work, return _default if error
}

static public int? GetInt(int? _default = null)
{
    // do work, return _default if error
}
```

I was hoping when using these methods as overrides that the method would be chosen also based on the variable I am using them to assign to:

```
int value1 = GetInt();
int? value2 = GetInt();
```

However this results in an "Ambiguous Invocation" error.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: The return type is never used in overload resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the return type is not part the [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of a method in C#. So you have to name the methods differently. Also, don't use underscore in parameter names.

To quote MSDN on how method signatures work:

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method and the
>   type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal
>   parameters, considered in the order left to right. The signature of a
>   method specifically does not include the return type, nor does it
>   include the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most
>   parameter.

This is a way to resolve it. As you return the default of the type, you can just make it generic and use `default(T)`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value1 = GetInt<int>();
        int? value2 = GetInt<int?>();
    }


    static public T GetInt<T>(T defaultValue = default(T))
    {
        bool error = true;
        if (error)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        else
        {
            //yadayada
            return something else;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not allow for the specification of the default value (`_default` in the question)

Comment: @Ryan well he did not specify that he wanted something other the default "default value", and I don't think he does

Comment: @Oskar The parameter is to allow the specification of other values as desired for defaults. For example, in some cases `-1` is the desired default for `int` but it depends on the variable being populated.

Answer (score 2):

Switch architecture.

```
 static public T GetInt<T>(T defaultValue = default(T))
    where T: struct
 {
     // Do Work.

     // On failure
     return defaultValue; 
 }
```

Then, when you call the function, you should benefit from the generic type:

```
 int value1 = GetInt(0);
 int? value2 = GetInt(default(int?));
```

Or if you want to omit the default value:

```
 int value1 = GetInt<int>();
 int? value2 = GetInt<int?>();
```

Alternatively, if you just want the default value, you can simply return

```
 return default(T);
```

UPDATE: Added constraint - obviously, the problem with making it generic is then you can supply any type; however, your problem then becomes making it compliant to turn an integer into `T`.

Comment: The new method wouldn't be required if you're specifying the arguments.. It's the optional parameter part of the question.

Comment: -1 doesn't compile. Why use `where T: struct`? Structs are non nullable, so `int?` is not valid